# Angular 2 - how to bind to a "dynamic" form field

Tags: angular, angular2-forms

I am building a form generator with Angular 2. The form fields are defined in a datastore somewhere and rendered as a form at runtime by my Angular 2 template. I am trying to setup form binding for the dynamic form, but haven't succeeded so far.

The first approach I took is below. An input element is rendered conditionally if the current form element ('element') if of type TEXT_INPUT. There is a model class ('model') defined in the backing component and I would like the input form element to bind to model.{{element.systemName}}.

```
<input *ngIf="element.type == 'TEXT_INPUT'" type="text"
[(ngModel)]="model.{{element.systemName}}" 
class="field-long" placeholder="{{element.label}}" 
name="{{element.systemName}}" />
```

This approach doesn't work. {{}} is not allowed as a value to ngModel.

My second approach didn't work either, because "this" doesn't exist.

```
<input (keyup)="updateModel(this)" (blur)="updateModel(this)"
*ngIf="element.type == 'TEXT_INPUT'" type="text" 
class="field-long" placeholder="{{element.label}}" 
name="{{element.systemName}}"/>
```

Is there some way I can refer to the current form element and send that to the backing component like updateModel(ref.to.current.form.element)?

It seems that placing **#myElementName** on the element would create a reference, which would allow me to call updateModel(myElementName). But there again I run into the problem that I need a dynamic name like this #{{element.systemName}}.

I am completely new to Angular 2, so I am hoping I am overlooking something obvious here.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You can reference the object using square brackets notation, like this:

```
<input *ngIf="element.type == 'TEXT_INPUT'" type="text"
[(ngModel)]="model[element.systemName]" />
```

Comment: This is not allowed: Parser Error: Unexpected token [, expected identifier or keyword at column 7 in [model.[element.systemName]] in DynamicFormComponent@16:65 ("
                    </select>

Answer (score 1):

There's an official documentation page about exactly this:

[Dynamic Forms](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/dynamic-form.html)

In it they build a questionnaire / survey form where the list of questions and their types (text, select, radio, etc) are stores in dynamic object (to simulate coming from DB).

The idea is:

1. `ngFor` for list of questions
2. Each question is the same component
3. The question component has ang `ngSwitch` that chooses which form control to use

See the [live example and source code](https://angular.io/generated/live-examples/dynamic-form/eplnkr.html).

Comment: That is pretty interesting. Thanks. It the example they JSON.stringify the whole form on submitting to see what is in the form. That seems a good approach as well.

Comment: Thanks. Looks like they changed the format of the URL. It's reachable via clicking "live sample" in the first link. I also updated the 2nd link to match the current URL.

Comment: If that was the reason for the downvote, please check the current version of the answer. Cheers.